# Typeerror in typescript (constructor)

Tags: typescript, class, constructor

What am I doing wrong?
there was an error like this :
TypeError: MainApp_1.MainApp is not a constructor

MainApp.ts :

```
export class MainApp {
  async login(url:string) {
    await t.expect(getUrl()).eql(url);
  }}
```

Smoke.ts :

```
import { ClientFunction, test } from "testcafe";
import MailosaurClient from "mailosaur";
import { Selector, t } from "testcafe";
import {MainApp} from "./MainApp";
const testUrl = `https://www.google.com/`;
const mainApp = new MainApp();
fixture("fixture")
  .page("https://www.google.com/")
  .beforeEach(async (t) => {
    console.log("test");
  })
  .disablePageCaching("fixture");

test("Test", async (t) => {
  console.log("Starting test");
  //Login
  await mainApp.login(
    testUrl
  );
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wQeBGw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: I can look when I get a chance (currently on mobile).  I generally do not downvote, and I can’t remove someone else’s.

Comment: Now that I'm looking [I still can't reproduce your problem](https://tsplay.dev/WPx2qW).  If you can't provide code that demonstrates the issue in a standalone IDE, can you provide a url to a web IDE project that demonstrates it?  If not then it is more difficult for someone else to debug this remotely.